# Difficulty with logistic regression: logit transformation is non-linear

Tags: regression, logistic, nonlinear-regression, biostatistics

I am trying to perform a logistic regression to model likelihood of receiving a procedure given a certain diagnosis. There are several covariates to analyze but one of the main ones is patient age. As a background to understanding the data, the incidence of this disease is highest among younger individuals and it is possible to understand outcomes as a dichotomous variable represented by “requires X procedure” or “does not require X procedure.”

My hypothesis was that because the incidence of this disease is lower in older individuals, it is possible that the likelihood of a poor outcome is higher due to delay in diagnosis (with the potential for many confounders that I would include in the analysis as best as possible). When I analyzed the distribution of the data, on first glance it appears that this may be the case:
[image: simple frequencies]

Presented as percent receiving "X" in equal weight age bins:
[image: agebin]

The trend in younger individuals has been described, but not the trend in older individuals.

However, when I compute the logistic regression, the model fits very poorly due to the non-linear relationship. See the Negelkerk R-squared Hosmer and Lemeshow statistics below. Looking at the classification table, the sensitivity of the model is 0, which I believe I should interpret as the model correctly predicting none of the patients who undergo the procedure.
[image: variables]
[image: omnibus]
[image: HLtest]
[image: classification table]

Analyzing the change in deviance and Cook’s distances shows a pattern to the model’s error, as expected due to the non-linear relationship.
[image: changedev]
[image: cooks]

Although I understand that the linearity assumption of the logistic regression is frequently violated, it seems obvious that this violation is too flagrant. However, I am at a loss for how to appropriately combine a non-linear transformation and a logistic regression. I would like to be able to describe an adjusted odds ratio for risk of procedure binned by age, if indeed it is significant.

Computing the regression with AGE and AGE^2 as terms increases the sensitivity slightly (to 8%) but the Negelkerk R-squared is still 0.042 and the Hosmer and Lemeshow statistic is 0.000. Adding a cubed term increases sensitivity to 11%, N-R-squared is 0.049 and H+L stat is 0.085. The change in deviance plot appears slightly more favorable:
[image: changedev2]

My question now is two-part: 1) Is there any transformation that would help the model fit better at the extremes? (Or simply increase sensitivity?) 2) How would I combine the exponentiated "B" coefficients to interpret one odds ratio as a function of age? My intuition is to somehow solve the B1,AGE^3+B2,AGE^2+B3,AGE+constant expression for a series of arbitrary age bins and combine the confidence intervals in a similar fashion, but this is definitely something I am not confident about.

Once again, thank you for any help or direction to information/tutorials!

Comment: Well, your plots indicate that the effect of AGE is non-linear, even non-monotone, so at the least you should include a quadratic term in age!, or use, maybe, a spline for age, like offered by R package mgcv.

Comment: Hi Kjetil, thank you for your advice! Unfortunately, I don't have any experience with R and am learning SPSS as I go along. If I were to apply a quadratic transformation to age before incorporating it into the logistic regression, would I still be able to interpret an adjusted odds ratio?

Comment: You should include age both as is (linear scale) and in addition its square, so you get two columns representing age. And yes, you can still interpret the odds ratio.

Comment: I think I understand the direction this is heading, do you think there is a better transformation I could try? (See edits)

Comment: It would be very helpful to see a useful exploratory analysis of the data, such as shown at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/138660 (but with dispersion statistics replaced by logits of means).

Comment: Or you could post here alink to data (or some large subset) for us to see into.

Comment: From that link, I believe this is the kind of analysis you were thinking of? Please correct me if I am wrong. [Logit](http://i.imgur.com/uyu4Cz6.png) The age bins are inclusive and "1" is received procedure; I calculated the log-odds for that age bin and plotted by age.

Comment: Happy to post a subset as well. I'll get to that this afternoon if this was not what you had in mind. Thank you again for your help. Unfortunately I don't have very many biostats resources to turn to with this project. Best, GCH

Comment: Better graph: [Better Log Odds graph](http://i.imgur.com/CLdTNhu.png)